# Store a huge html string in a string variable

Tags: android

I have this html string:

```
<h1>MDPI Open Access Information and Policy</h1>

<div class="info-intro">All articles published by MDPI are made available under an open access license worldwide immediately. This means:
<ul>
```

And i would like to store this in a string:

```
String abaut="<h1>MDPI Open Access Information and Policy</h1>

<div class="info-intro">All articles published by MDPI are made available under an open access license worldwide immediately. This means:
<ul>";
```

And i am gotting some problems: the string is not accepted because of some " inside of the string and some new lines. How can I do this differently?

Comment: `i am gotting some problems` Very good problem description!

Comment: sorry for this @WarrenFaith, i edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you need to escape the `"` inside your string. Use `\"` instead.

Sample:

```
String abaut="<h1>MDPI Open Access Information and Policy</h1>" +
"<div class=\"info-intro\">All articles published by MDPI are made available under an open access license worldwide immediately. This means: <ul>";
```